# mockito - checking if condition passes and calls a method which does not return anythig

Tags: java, methods, mockito, invoke, stub

I have the following service class:

```
 class Person() {

   AgeDAO dao;
   Speaker speaker;

   public method checkSpeak( List<Jon> list) {
        List<Integer> ages = dao.getAge(list);

        if ( ages != null && !ages.isEmpty() ) {
           speaker.speak(list);
        }

   }   

 }
```

Test class:

```
 @Test
 class MyTest {

    void speakTest() {
        Person p = new Person();
        Speaker speaker = mock(Speaker.class); 
        p.speaker = speaker;

        AgeDAO dao = mock(AgeDAO.class);
        p.dao = dao;

        List<Jon> list = createJonList();
        List<Integer> ages = createAgesList();
        when(dao.getAge(anyList())).thenReturn(ages);
        p.checkSpeak(ages);

        verify(p.speaker).speak(anyList()); // This is not called/invoked.

    }
 }
```

I just want to verify `speak` is invoked. Should I still mock the method? If I need to mock the method, how do I mock the method that does not return anything. `when` requires a method return something.

Comment: Please show the full code of the `Person` class; also, why use a bean instead of an immutable class? (as it is now, `Person` cannot compile)

Comment: Also, you seem to have two `.getAge()` methods: you call `dao.getAge(anyInt())` but in your code you have `dao.getAge(someJon)`. Show more code.

Comment: Real code is too big and too many things. I just emulated the logic with sample. AgeDAO and Speaker are EJBs injected.

Comment: Another thing: why `any(Jon.class)` when you can just substitute it with `j`?

Comment: Of course, we can. But issue is not with that.

Comment: Sorry, but it _is_ an issue here; instead of specifying that you want the `speak` method to be called with your argument that you have created, here it may be called with any `Jon`.

Comment: Lets assume there is `anyList()` instead of Jon in `when` and `verify` and getAge takes a list. Would you think it should invoke then?

Comment: This would not even compile since the `.getAge()` method does not take a `List` as an argument. What I said is that you build a person with `j`, but with any other `Jon` instance your test would still pass. Not what you want, is it?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say `getAge` takes list. In all places, "assume" there is a `list of jons`, so I can simply use `anyList` in stubbing/mocking. Now I just wanted to verify `speak` method is invoked.

Comment: OK, this is becoming very murky here. Please edit your question so as to provide the _real_ code.

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: And what does that `createJsonList()` method does?

Comment: It just returns list of Jons.

Comment: Not enough. OK, try and debug within your program and see what happens when you invoke the actual method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few minor problems in the code you posted (most notably: `checkSepak` takes a `List<Jon>` but your code is passing `ages` which is a `List<Integer>`).

After fixing these I realized that the test is failing because the `ages` list, created by the test (and used as the return value of `dao.getAges()`), is empty. Thus, the condition `ages != null && !ages.isEmpty()` is not satisfied which make the code skip over the `speaker.speak()` call.

The obvious solution is to make the `ages` list non-empty by adding some element to it:

```
public class MyTest {
  @Test
  public void speakTest() {
    Person p = new Person();
    Speaker speaker = mock(Speaker.class);
    p.speaker = speaker;

    AgeDAO dao = mock(AgeDAO.class);
    p.dao = dao;

    List<Jon> list = createJonList();
    List<Integer> ages = createAgesList();
    ages.add(5);  // Make the list of ages non-empty
    when(dao.getAge(anyList())).thenReturn(ages);
    p.checkSpeak(list);

    verify(p.speaker).speak(anyList());

  }

  private List<Integer> createAgesList() {
    return new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  private List<Jon> createJonList() {
    return new ArrayList<Jon>();
  }
}

class Person {
  AgeDAO dao;
  Speaker speaker;

  public void checkSpeak(List<Jon> list) {
    List<Integer> ages = dao.getAge(list);

    if (ages != null && !ages.isEmpty()) {
      speaker.speak(list);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to mock the object for Speaker since you only used "when" for dao. Unless Speaker has objects that needs to be mocked that would cause the speak method to fail, you should not have to mock Speaker. Try doing p.speaker = new Speaker();  This is the best guess since I'm not sure what Speaker class code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the speak method with [doNothing](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing%28%29)